# How can I use textbox to write the user key input? (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Basically, I'm trying to write in a TextBox the key corresponding to the user input. The problem is that the key pressed will be entered as well

XAML code :

```
<TextBox
    Name="TextBox1"
    PreviewKeyDown="OnTextBoxOneKeyDown">
</TextBox>
```

xaml.cs code :

```
private void OnTextBoxOneKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = e.Key.ToString();
}
```

Unfortunately, if for example I type the letter 's', in the textBox, it will be written 'sS' instead of just 'S'. If I type 'a', it will be written 'aA' istead of 'A'. The reason I need the keyDown event is that I want to write in the textBox if the user pressed 'Space', 'shift', numbers from the numpad, etc.

Thank you

Comment: Explain what you want write in the textBox if the user pressed 'Space' etc. please

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, if the user press Space, it will be written 'Space' just like the method e.Key.ToString would return normally, but the problem was that it would also add the character space. for example         ' Space' vs 'Space'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get such behaviour since both `PreviewKeyDown` and `KeyDown` are called. You just need to tell that you dont need to process it further by setting `e.Handled = true`

```
private void OnTextBoxOneKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = e.Key.ToString();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```